# Getting the most recent versions of entries in a Django model with versioned data

Tags: django, django-orm

The application I'm working on has a schedule which assigns workers to work in different locations at different time blocks. The schedule is versioned through a `ChangeSet` model. Each `ScheduleEntry` references a `ChangeSet`.

```py
class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class TimeBlock(models.Model)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

class ChangeSet(models.Model):
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class ScheduleEntry(models.Model):
    change_set = models.ForeignKey(ChangeSet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(Worker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_block = models.ForeignKey(TimeBlock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

A worker can only be assigned to one location for each time block. This location is is determined by the `ScheduleEntry` with the most recent non-null `change_set.published_on` for that worker and time block.

A `Worker` could be unscheduled (have `None` for their location) either because there aren't any schedule entries for the worker in that time block, the entries are all linked to unpublished change sets, or the most recent published entry specifies `null` as the `location`.

Getting the current published schedule location in a specific time block for a worker is easy:

```py
ScheduleEntry.objects.filter(
    change_set__published_on__isnull=False,
    worker=my_worker,
    time_block=my_time_block,
).order_by('-change_set__published_on').first()
```

However, I can't figure out how to perform a query to get things like:

- Full schedule for a worker, across all time blocks
- All workers scheduled to work at a specific location in a specific time block

In other words, I want a query that returns all schedule entries which belong to published change sets and have not been overwritten by a subsequent entry for the same worker/time_block pair with a more recent `change_set.published_on` value. Once I have that, I can further refine the query with filters to get entries by location, time block, or person.

I thought of applying a `.distinct('worker', 'time_block')` to the query, but passing field names is a PostgreSQL only feature and I'm currently using SQLite.

Is this something that can be efficiently expressed in SQL and Django ORM?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this question later, this is the solution I arrived at in the end:

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Exists

ScheduleEntry.objects.filter(
  change_set__published_on__isnull=False,
).exclude(
  Exists(
    ScheduleEntry.objects.filter(
      worker=OuterRef('worker'),
      time_block=OuterRef('time_block'),
      change_set__published_on__isnull=False,
      change_set__published_on__gt=OuterRef('change_set__published_on'),
    )
  )
)
```

The outer query first filters records to only include those that are part of a published change set (`change_set__published_on__isnull=False`). It then excludes records (`.exclude`) if the inner turns out any records (`Exists`).

The inner query looks in the model for any records with the same `worker` as the outer query (`worker=OuterRef('worker')`), the same `time_block`, that is part of a published change set (`.._isnull=False`) and *most crucially* are part of a later change set (`change_set__published_on__gt=OuterRef('change_set__published_on')`).

Effectively what this does is it excludes entries that have been "overwritten" in a subsequent change set, thus keeping only the most recent version for each entry.